# Fill missing values in Pandas dataframe with items in list

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to fill missing values in dataframe with items from list?
For example:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8],[10,11,12],[13,14]])

        0   1   2
    0   1   2   3
    1   4   5 NaN
    2   7   8 NaN
    3  10  11  12
    4  13  14 NaN

list = [6, 9, 150]
```

to get some something like this:

```
       0   1   2
   0   1   2   3
   1   4   5   6
   2   7   8   9
   3  10  11  12
   4  13  14  15
```

Comment: what if you have two columns both of which have missing values? What order do you use to fill those missing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is actually a little tricky and a bit of a hack, if you know the column you want to fill the `NaN` values for then you can construct a df for that column with the indices of the missing values and pass the df to `fillna`:

```
In [33]:
fill = pd.DataFrame(index =df.index[df.isnull().any(axis=1)], data= [6, 9, 150],columns=[2])
df.fillna(fill)

Out[33]:
    0   1    2
0   1   2    3
1   4   5    6
2   7   8    9
3  10  11   12
4  13  14  150
```

You can't pass a dict (my original answer) as the dict key values are the column values to match on and the scalar value will be used for all `NaN` values for that column which is not what you want:

```
In [40]:
l=[6, 9, 150]
df.fillna(dict(zip(df.index[df.isnull().any(axis=1)],l)))

Out[40]:
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   9
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
4  13  14   9
```

You can see that it has replaced all `NaN`s with `9` as it matched the missing `NaN` index value of `2` with column `2`.